# Need help to create a JavsScript array that will store several squares in a straight line on top of a existing polygon using Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome

I have a html file that I included here. The file has text boxes and one push button. The push button will be activated in JavaScript file.

When the JavaScript runs it has an initialization section that loads the Google Maps tool to do certain measurements of a location or roof.

**I need to create a function that will do the followings:** 
The existing code is already creating a square area or polygon. So idea is to create few smaller squares those will fit into the existing square in a straight line with small spaces in between of the squares.

I have attached the JavaScript code and highlighted the section where this new function or code should evolve.

I just started learning JavaScript specially google map API and I am stuck. Please assist me how I can implement this, it will be monumental help.

JavaScript file

```js
// JavaScript source code

'use strict';
var mapScript = (function () { 

    var GMap; // global variable within the solar module scope
    var squarePolys = []; //global array of Shape that will be attached to google maps

    function initMap() {
        // Load map at default location
        GMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: { lat: ‎37.76963799867498, lng:‎ ‎-122.45126726263503 },                
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
            draggableCursor: 'crosshair',
            zoom: 20,
            disableDefaultUI: true
        });

        // force orthorgraphic imagery
        GMap.setTilt(0);

        // wait till map display is fully updated before drawing an area or roof section
        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(GMap, "projection_changed", makeASite);

        //Hook up the 
        var createButton = $("#create-button");
        createButton.click(function () {
            makeASite();
        });
    }

    //creating an area with modules
    function makeASite() {
        deletePreviousSite(); //removed any old polgyons first

        // draw default area or roof rectangle
        var rAreaSqPoly = constructRFSqPoly();
        squarePolys.push(rAreaSqPoly);

        // Create unites
        var unites = makeUnits(rAreaSqPoly);
        for (var i = 0; i < unites.length; i++) {
            squarePolys.push(unites[i]);
        }

        render();
    }

    // Create the default roof or an area rectangle
    function constructRFSqPoly() {
        //  The areas rectangle definition. 
        //  Center:   the latitude, longitude location of the center of the rectangle
        //  Width:    width of rectangel in meters
        //  Height:   height of rectangel 
        //  rotation: rotation angle of rectangle
        var rAreaSqPolyChoices = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.76963799867498, -122.45126726263503),
            width: 40.46, // meters
            length: 28.35, 
            rotation: 20, // degrees
            color: '#0072ff',  
            googleMap: GMap
        };

        // Create a google Shape object to overlay on the aerial
        return new Shape(rAreaSqPolyChoices);
    }

    // Create a list of pv module rectangles those will be later attached to the map
    function makeUnits(rAreaSqPoly) {
        var unitSqPolys = [];

        var unitWd = Number($("#site-width").val());
        var unitLn = Number($("#site-length").val());
        var unitSp = Number($("#site-spacing").val());

        ****Here I want to draw unites (square/polygon) on top of an 
        exiting polygon (this could be a car parking lot or roof). The 
        square are a straight line with spaces in between**** 

        return unitSqPolys;
    }

    // Redraws each Shape in the Shape list
    function render() {
        for (var i = 0; i < squarePolys.length; i++) {
            var Shape = squarePolys[i];
            Shape.clearMap();
            Shape.attachToMap();
        }
    }

    //Removes old Shapes from map and clears out the Shape list
    function deletePreviousSite() {
        for (var i = 0; i < squarePolys.length; i++) {
            var Shape = squarePolys[i];
            Shape.clearMap();
        }
        squarePolys = [];
    }

    var Shape = (function () { //This is the class definition for Shape
        //Width and length are in distance units,
        //Center is a google maps point in lat,lng coordinates
        //Rotation is in degress
        function Shape(options) 
         { //This is the constructor for thos class
            // if(width !== "number" || length !== "number" || center !== "object", rotation !== "number")
            // throw new Error("Invalid arguments for constructing a Shape object");
            var _self = this;
            _self.width = options.width;
            _self.length = options.length;
            _self.center = options.center;
            _self.rotation = options.rotation;
            _self.googleMap = options.googleMap;
            _self.color = typeof options.color === "string" ? options.color : "#0072ff";
            _self.line = [];

            createShape();
            // In JavaScript member functions declared inside the contruction are private
            function createShape() {
                // Create rectangle coordinates, in latitude, longitude space to define an area or roof section of rectangle
                var line = [
                    Shape.setValuesInMtr(_self.center, _self.length / 2, -1 * _self.width / 2),
                    Shape.setValuesInMtr(_self.center, -1 * _self.length / 2, -1 * _self.width / 2),
                    Shape.setValuesInMtr(_self.center, -1 * _self.length / 2, 1 * _self.width / 2),
                    Shape.setValuesInMtr(_self.center, _self.length / 2, _self.width / 2)
                ];

                // Rotate the coordinates by the angle relative to the center of it
                _self.line = moveline(line, _self.rotation, _self.center);

                _self.googleMapsShape = new google.maps.Shape({
                    lines: _self.line,
                    strokeColor: _self.color,
                    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                    strokeWeight: 2,
                    fillColor: _self.color,
                    fillOpacity: 0.35
                });
            }

            // Rotates an input array of latitude, longitude locations by the specified
            // angle around the specified latitude/longitude center
            function moveline(line, angle, origin) {
                var thisProjection = _self.googleMap.getProjection();

                var originPt = thisProjection.fromLatLngToPoint(origin);

                var moveOrders = line.map(function (latLng) {
                    var point = thisProjection.fromLatLngToPoint(latLng);

                    var rotatedLatLng = thisProjection.fromPointToLatLng(circulatePts(point, originPt, angle));
                    return rotatedLatLng;
                });
                return moveOrders;
            };

            // Rotation transformation
            function circulatePts(point, origin, angle) {
                var thisAngleR = angle * Math.PI / 180.0;
                return {
                    x: Math.cos(thisAngleR) * (point.x - origin.x) - Math.sin(thisAngleR) * (point.y - origin.y) + origin.x,
                    y: Math.sin(thisAngleR) * (point.x - origin.x) + Math.cos(thisAngleR) * (point.y - origin.y) + origin.y
                };
            }
        }


        //Attaches Shape to google maps
        Shape.prototype.attachToMap = function () { //public member function
            this.googleMapsShape.setMap(this.googleMap);
        };

        //Removes this Shape from google maps
        Shape.prototype.clearMap = function () { //public member function
            this.googleMapsShape.setMap(null);
        };

        // When provide a latitude, longitude location, and a distance north as well as east,
        // will return a new latitude, longitude location by the distances.
        Shape.setValuesInMtr = function (pointLatLng, nhMeters, eTMeters)
        { //Public static member function
            
            var R = 6378137; //PlanetEarth’s radius, sphere

            //offsets in radians
            var dLat = nhMeters / R;
            var dLon = eTMeters / (R * Math.cos(Math.PI * pointLatLng.lat() / 180));

            return new google.maps.LatLng(
                pointLatLng.lat() + dLat * 180 / Math.PI,
                pointLatLng.lng() + dLon * 180 / Math.PI);
        };

        return Shape
    })();

    return {
        initMap: initMap
    }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple Map To Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #map {
            height: 60%;
            width: 60%;
        }

        #site-input {
            margin: 10px;
        }

        input {
            margin: 5px;
        }

        button {
            margin: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="site-input">
        Wd: <input type="text" id="site-width" value="5"><br>
        Ln: <input type="text" id="site-length" value="7"><br>
        Sp: <input type="text" id="site-spacing" value="0"><br>
        <button id="create-button">Create</button><br>
    </div>

    <div id="map"></div>

    <script src="./mapScript.js"></script>
    
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=mapScript.initMap" async defer></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want a checkerboard grid on top of the roof of that wine store ... , right? is id="site-spacing" the number of meters between the grid lines?

Comment: Hi Emmanuel, Thank you for your time, I appreciated.  Yes,  one straight line of grid like you have mentioned on top of the roof. However function should be dynamic enough to create as many grid as needed. Also id="site-spacing" is for space between grid. Thanks a lot

Comment: Please I need help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, try this.

This is not the final form.  Look what happens, tell me which input and buttons you need ...

I made it (pretty much) from scratch, because it's easier for me to concentrate on the problem and forget all the rest.
Bu you should definitly put it back in your code format, with var mapScript = (function () { ...

The main weapon is the geometry library, which you have to load :
maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap&libraries=geometry
(again, in your code this would be mapScript.initMap )

it gives you

- computeOffset (you give a point A, a distance and a heading, it returns point B)
- computeHeading (you give a point A and point B, it returns the heading)
- computeDistanceBetween (you give a point A and point B, it returns the distance)

---

instructions:

- you can fill in point A and point B (the heading input is calculated, it doesn't change anything, it just tells you the angle)

or

- click on the map, first for point A.  Click again for point B.  Then the function is automatically loaded, it reads the spacing/rows/cols data and makes the grid.

index.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Simple Map To Test</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #map {
        height: 60%;
        width: 60%;
    }
    #site-input {
        margin: 10px;
    }
    input {
        margin: 5px;
    }
    button {
        margin: 5px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="site-input">
    Wd: <input type="text" id="site-width" value="5"><br>
    Ln: <input type="text" id="site-length" value="7"><br>
    Sp: <input type="text" id="site-spacing" value="5"><br>
    <button id="create-button">Create</button><br>
</div>
<div>
  <input id="origin" placeholder="origin" value="37.7695505,-122.4513206" />
  <input id="x" placeholder="x" value="37.7695722,-122.45114699" />
  <input id="heading" placeholder="heading" value="80.0" />
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="js.js"></script>    
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap&libraries=geometry" async defer></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

js.js

```
function initMap() {
  GMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: { lat: 37.76963799867498, lng: -122.45126726263503 },                
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
    draggableCursor: 'crosshair',
    zoom: 20,
    disableDefaultUI: true
  });
  GMap.setTilt(0);

  var state = 0;    // 'origin', 'x'
  var heading = 0;  //   0 = heading north, 90 = heading east
  var originMarker = null;
  var xMarker = null;
  // polyline objects will be stored in these arrays
  var xLines = [];
  var yLines = [];

  // click on button
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('create-button'), 'click', function() {
    removeAll();
    var latData = document.getElementById('origin').value.split(',');
    var lngData = document.getElementById('x').value.split(',');
    var pathPoints = [
      new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(latData[0]), parseFloat(latData[1])),
      new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lngData[0]), parseFloat(lngData[1]))
    ];
    createGrid(pathPoints, GMap, xLines, yLines);
  });

  // click on map
  GMap.addListener('click', function(event) {
    var lat = event.latLng.lat();
    var lng = event.latLng.lng();
    switch (state) {
      case 0: // first click: user sets origin
        removeAll();
        originMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: event.latLng,
          title: 'point A',
          map: GMap
        });
        // display
        document.getElementById('origin').value = lat +','+ lng;
        state++;
        break;
      case 1: // second click: now we can calculate the heading (heading = x-axis; heading +90° = y-axis)
        xMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: event.latLng,
          title: 'point B',
          map: GMap
        });
        document.getElementById('x').value = lat +','+ lng;
        heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(
          originMarker.getPosition(),
          xMarker.getPosition()
        );
        document.getElementById('heading').value = heading;
        var pathPoints = [
          {lat: originMarker.getPosition().lat(), lng: originMarker.getPosition().lng()},
          {lat: xMarker.getPosition().lat(), lng: xMarker.getPosition().lng()}
        ];
        createGrid([originMarker.getPosition(),xMarker.getPosition()], GMap, xLines, yLines);

        state = 0;
        break;

    }
  });
  //  remove all previous elements
  function removeAll() {

    if(originMarker) {originMarker.setMap(null);} 
    if(xMarker) {xMarker.setMap(null);} 
    for(var i in xLines) {xLines[i].setMap(null);}
    for(var i in yLines) {yLines[i].setMap(null);}

    state = 0;    
    heading = 0; 
    originMarker = null;
    xMarker = null;

    xLines = [];
    yLines = [];
  }

}

//
function createGrid(pathPoints, GMap, xLines, yLines) {
  var spacing = parseFloat(document.getElementById('site-spacing').value);
  var cols = parseInt(document.getElementById('site-width').value);
  var rows = parseInt(document.getElementById('site-length').value);

  var pointA = pathPoints[0];
  var pointB = pathPoints[1];
  var heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(pointA, pointB);
  var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(pointA, pointB);

  for(var i=0; spacing && i<cols; i++) {
    // let's look for point C, on the line A-B, at a distance 'spacing' of point A
    // @see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeControlOptions
    // computeOffset(from:LatLng, distance:number, heading:number, radius?:number)

    var pointC = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(pointA, i * spacing, heading);
    var pointD = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(pointC, rows * spacing, heading - 90);

    //// put a test marker there
    //var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    //  position: pointC,
    //  title: 'point C',
    //  map: GMap
    //});
    var pathPoints = [
      {lat: pointC.lat(), lng: pointC.lng()},
      {lat: pointD.lat(), lng: pointD.lng()}
    ];
    xLines[i] = polyline(pathPoints, GMap, '#00ff00');       
  }

  for(var i=0; spacing && i<rows; i++) {
    var pointG = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(pointA, i * spacing, heading - 90);
    var pointH = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(pointG, cols * spacing, heading);
    //// put a test marker there
    //var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    //  position: pointG,
    //  title: 'point G',
    //  map: GMap
    //});

    var pathPoints = [
      {lat: pointG.lat(), lng: pointG.lng()},
      {lat: pointH.lat(), lng: pointH.lng()}
    ];
    yLines[i] = polyline(pathPoints, GMap, '#00ff00');
  }

}

// returns a polyline object
function polyline(pathPoints, map, color) {
    // color
    if(typeof color == 'undefined') {
      color  ='#FF0000';
    }
    return new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: pathPoints,
      geodesic: true,
      strokeColor: color,
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      map: map
    });
}
```